# EF Core navigational property for an existing static data table

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have two simple entities:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SKU { get; set; }
    public ProductCatalog Catalog { get; set; }
}

public class ProductCatalog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public ProductCatalogType Type { get; set; }
}
```

`ProductCatalog` table already has static data in the database.

When I am inserting a new `Product`, I am setting the `Id` property of the `Catalog` object to be inserted as foreign key on the `Product` table, however Entity Framework tries to insert data into the `ProductCatalog` table.

How do I keep the relationship between two entities but disallow insert/update of `Catalog` data when inserting new `Product`?

Note, I still would like to have the ability to join the two entities during my selects.

I tried setting

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().Ignore(c => c.Catalog)
```

but I am not sure this is the right approach.